# Is it paint or wallpaper?

Tags: drywall, paint, patching-drywall, wallpaper

[image]We got recessed lights installed and are looking to do some patchwork over the small nails that the lights were installed on. In my home, the previous owner has provided both paint as well as wallpaper. Clearly the walls aren't smoothly painted, they have some uneven patterns (exactly like the one in this youtube video https://youtu.be/6fCW69gXqfg&t=6m30s around minute 6:30).

Could you help me telling if its wallpaper or painted over?

I understand how to patch up the small holes, but when finishing it, how do i exactly recreate the wall texture? Should i stick the wallpaper or should i put the wallpaper and paint over it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry, the link was a mistake, it didn't have the timestamp. Fixed now!

Comment: Watch the video that you provided. There's no wallpaper involved. The texture is drywall mud. https://www.homedepot.com/p/USG-Sheetrock-Brand-3-5-qt-Dust-Control-Ready-Mixed-Joint-Compound-384014/206075509, for instance. The "dust control" labeling is marketing BS.

Comment: What have the lights got to do with it?

Comment: Updated the post with a photo, could you help now!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your walls look like one can only assume they match the texture from the video. If that is the case, no, it is not wallpaper but a style of drywall texture. People around my area refer to that as *old world* texture (*it may called something else in other locations*).

You'd have to watch some videos on how to recreate it, I'm not familiar with the technique myself just the style.

Comment: Updated the post with a photo, could you help now!

Comment: @Annonymous It almost looks like a knockdown with orange peel on top. Not really sure what is going on. Can you upload some more photos.